# Dependency of function of independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$X$ and $Y$ are independent and identically distributed random variables, $c$ is a constant. I wonder if $\frac{1}{X+c}$, and $\frac{1}{Y+c}$ are independent? In other words, are the functions of independent random variables also independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a different light to Mason's excellent answer that is more intuitive and less rigorous, note that two random variables are independent if knowing ``the outcome'' of one doesn't tell you anything about the other. Clearly if $X$ didn't help you know $Y$ any better, than $g(X)$ won't help you know $h(Y)$ any better. Again this isn't a formal proof like Mason's but you should intuitively understand why this is true.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are independent.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, let $g$ and $h$ be real-valued functions defined on the codomains of $X$ and $Y$ respectively.
Then $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ are independent random variables.

Proof can be found here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Functions_of_Independent_Random_Variables_are_Independent